# Can you use LevelDB with Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, leveldb

I'm looking at persistent stores for hybrid / cordova / phonegap app.

Is LevelDB an option (can it replace sqlite or can is there an adapter for level.js to use sqlite as a backend?)

Thanks!